# Ubuntu Boot Time Takes 2.5 Minutes (Ubuntu Budgie 17.04)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ubuntu-budgie

so after installing Ubuntu Budgie on my gaming PC, it takes an excessive amount of time to boot. Almost two minutes! I am running this off of a 320 gb 7200 RPM hard drive. This system itself works great, just slow boot up. If this is all I have to deal with, I'm very happy. :)

Comment: Run this `systemd-analyze blame` and post the result.

Comment: Show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `free -h` and `swapon -s`. Edit that output into your question, not the comments, please. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have that info and I'll take a look.